# Can I persist data with kue / node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, persistence, kue

I am currently working with kue / node.js

https://github.com/Automattic/kue

After i create and save a job the data will be in my local redis server .

```
  var job = queue.create('new_job', {
        title: 'welcome email for tj'
        , to: 'tj@learnboost.com'
        , template: 'welcome-email'
    }).save( function(err){
        if( !err ) console.log( job.id );
    });
```

Redis Cli

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
 1) "q:job:12"
 2) "q:jobs:inactive"
 3) "q:stats:work-time"
 4) "q:ids"
 5) "q:job:11"
 6) "q:job:7"
 7) "q:search:object:13"
 8) "q:search:word:TTL"
 9) "q:search:object:2"
10) "q:jobs:new_job:inactive"
  ..........
```

now after i restart my machine and checked again ,

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
(empty list or set)
```

So it is empty .

This is obvious , but i want to persist the data , i checked the kue documentation but i could not find anything ?

Is there any way to do this .

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the persistence can be handled by your redis server configuration. In your [redis.conf](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf), you have a section commented `snapshotting` which you should explore. There are a number of ways to configure persistence, but I think what best suits your use case is AOF wherein all incoming writes to the redis server are logged to a file. Please do read about how redis can be configured for persistence [here](http://redis.io/topics/persistence). You can turn on AOF persistence by adding this line to your conf file:

```
appendonly true
```

Comment: Thank you very much . i will look into this :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, kue doesn't remove jobs unless you delete jobs manually.

Here is an example, saved as test.js:

```
const kue = require('kue')
const queue = kue.createQueue()
queue.process('echo', (job, done) => {
  console.log(job.data.message)
  done();
})
const job = queue.create('echo', {
  message: 'hello world'
}).save((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(job.id)
  }
})
```

When I execute via

```
node test.js
```

I check queue info in redis, the result of `redis-cli keys "q*"` is below:

[image]

Then I restart `node test.js`, the result of `redis-cli keys "q*" is below:

[image]

Actually, here add a new task: `q:job:2`. `kue` will remove a job when you call `job.remove`. So you should check redis-server's log file to see what happened.